# The Composition of Two rotations

Tags: transformation, reflection, transformational-geometry

[image: Question 7.10. Find Q and Theta such that composition of halfturns (d,c,b,a) is Rho(Q,Theta)]

So far I rewrote the halfturns of d,c,b,a to halfturn (p,n)(m,l) where n=m because lines c and d are parallel so I can make ambiguous lines n and p parallel too. I also know that lines c,d can be shifted up or down so the distance between lines m=n and p is the same as the distance between c,d where lines m=n goes through a point A. Point A is where lines a and b intersect. 
   From this, I can see that the product of 4 reflections can be broken down into just 2 because of the definition of an even isometry. So I get product of reflections of lines p,n,m,l is equal to product of reflections p and l. 
   Now I have to find what the line l is. Line l goes through point A with but I am not sure at what angle. is the 60 degrees already given to me? 
   Another question is- After I find line l, I know that it intersects the line p that i found but how do i define the point where it intersects if i call that point C? Example, my answer comes out as Rho(C,and the addition of the interior angles on lines p and l where the both rotate to what line? 
   Can someone please help me? I have been stuck with this question for a while now. Thank you.